# Switch statement with numeric values

Tags: javascript

Trying simple switch with random number.
It does not seem to work. Always getting to `default` case.

```
var x = 0;
x = (Math.random() * 10 + 1); 

switch(x)  {
  case x >= 5:
    console.log("the number is bigger than 5");
    break;
  case x <= 5:
    console.log("the number is smaller than 5");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("strange number");
}

console.log(x);
```

The output is always similar to that:

```
strange number
5.922413225153608
```

Comment: `switch (x) case x >= 5` actually means `if (x === x >= 5)`…

Comment: `switch` `case`s are evaluated then matched to the `switch(argument)`.

Answer (score 5):

That's just not how `switch` statements work in JavaScript,<sup>1</sup> what you're looking for there is an `if/else if/else` series instead:

```
if (x >= 5) {
    console.log("the number is bigger than 5");
} else if (x <= 5) {
    console.log("the number is smaller than 5");
} else {
    console.log("strange number");
}
```

Two notes, though:

1. Your first and second cases both include 5; the first will win.
2. The only value for `x` that will reach the final `else` is `NaN` (or something that converts to `NaN` when converted to number), because `NaN >= 5` and `NaN <= 5` are both `false`.

---

In a comment you've said:

> Thanks, the point is to practice `switch`.

If so, you'll either have to do the thing below (which probably isn't what your instructor wanted), or limit the range of values, because the cases of a switch are tested for **exact** match.

For instance, if you changed your code only allow integers, you could use cases with fall-through:

```
var x = 0;
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);  // Note change: Only integers

switch(x)  {
  case 5:
  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8:
  case 9:
  case 10:
    console.log("the number is bigger than 5");
    break;
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
    console.log("the number is smaller than 5");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("strange number");
}
console.log(x);
```

That makes use of the fact that cases *fall through* to the following case when you don't use `break`.

But you can't do that with your original `x`, because there are just too many floating-point values in the range `1 <= x < 11` to list.

---

JavaScript's `switch` does have a feature that makes it possible to use `switch` here, but an `if/else if/else` is almost certainly a better choice. Purely for completeness:

```
// PROBABLY NOT A GOOD IDEA
switch (true) {
    case x >= 5:
        console.log("the number is bigger than 5");
        break;
    case x <= 5:
        console.log("the number is smaller than 5");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("strange number");
        break;
}
```

That works because unlike many languages, JavaScript's `switch` `case`s are allowed to be expressions, and they're tested in the order in which they appear in the `switch` (other than `default`, of course), with the first matching `case` being used.

But again, probably not great to use in the real world except in very, very limited situations.

Comment: Thanks, the point is to practice switch. Does it have to do with numbers?

Comment: Actually this is good to have that last "else", because who knows what will be passed. It is good to see it while debugging.

Comment: @AndreyStolbovsky: I didn't say it wasn't good, I just wanted to be clear about what woudl get there. :-)

Comment: @SergeyVasilenko: See update above if it has to be `switch`, two options for you (the one at the end I'd already added, but I added another in the middle).

Answer (score 3):

Between `case` and `:` you have to have a *value*.

`x >= 5` and `x <= 5` are going to give you `true` or `false`, which `x` will then be compared to. Since `x` will always be a number, it will never be `true` or `false` so you will always hit the `default`.

Use `if`/`else if`/`else` instead.

Comment: *"Between `case` and `:` you have to have a value."* Not in JavaScript. Any expression is allowed. They're evaluated in order.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — Yes, but the expression is evaluated to a value and that is what is used for the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do in thatway. You have to do

```
switch(true)  {
  case x >= 5:
      console.log("the number is bigger than 5");
      break;
  case x <= 5:
     console.log("the number is smaller than 5");
     break;
  default:
     console.log("strange number");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

While [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is using strict comparison and you have already in the `case` clause already a comparison, you could change your `switch` statement to

```
switch(true) {
```

and use the rest, you have.

Comment: While not semantically correct, this works and is the best 'solution' for the problem here. Not that I would recommend using it.